# How to specify the `learn-filename` when using `learnf` tag in AIML?

Tags: aiml

A quick question how and where do you specify the filename of your destination *.aiml file when using `learnf` tag? The documentation states that

> the generated category is written to an .aiml file that you may specify with the property learn-filename

but I'm not sure what is meant here by "property".

Should it be located in `properties` file? Or maybe a tag inside a `learnf` tag? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a bot property. here is a sample of my file:
It goes in the same file as the rest of your bot properties, name, age, location etc

[image]